# RegEx finding item before not after

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get the value out of this element via Regex (not xml). I need the word Description out of the element.

```
<ValueExpressionLeft xmlns="http://Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Core.Criteria/">
 <Property>$Context/Property[Type='WorkItem!System.WorkItem']/Description$</Property>
</ValueExpressionLeft>
```

This only returns what appears after type=

```
 string typeString = Regex.Match(valueExpressionLeft.Value.ToString(), "(?<=Type=\')[^\']+").Value;
```

I need to get the word description after the `]/`

I tried kessly's subbestion below to no avail:

```
value left only containts this 
$Context/Property[Type='WorkItem!System.WorkItem']/Description$

string left =valueExpressionLeft.Value.ToString();

string fieldname =Regex.Match(left,@"\[Type=\'.*\']/([^<]+)[</]").Value;
```

Comment: Why do you use a regex for that?

Comment: Because its matching for elements within a string regex is always suggested for speed as suppose to substring

Comment: How do you know you need Description? What's the key point that means that's what you need? Item after Property? Final part? Something else?

Comment: Well its not the word description its the value after ]/ to the </property> tag  it is used as a field name within SSCM

Comment: @user1676075 hence I noted that below the string typestring does anyone bother to read a post in full without deflamming

Comment: I'm not sure what deflamming is, but if you just want everything from ]/ to the end, it would be quicker and easier to just get the Property value and do value.substring(value.indexOf("]/")+2);

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are JUST looking for the word `Description$`?

If so the following regex should get you that chuck of data:

```
\[Type=\'.*\'\]/([^<]+)[</]
```

Group $1: `Description$`

**EDIT:** To answer you comment, yes it does work in .net.  Here is the full example but really you should read up on the Regex documentation:

```
string parseText = "<ValueExpressionLeft xmlns='http://Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Core.Criteria/'><Property>$Context/Property[Type='WorkItem!System.WorkItem']/Description$</Property></ValueExpressionLeft>";
Match match = Regex.Match(parseText, @"\[Type=\'.*\'\]/([^<]+)[</]");
string field = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

If you want to get rid of the `$` at the end you could use the following regex:

```
\[Type=\'.*\'\]/([^<]+)[\$]
```

Comment: Second group value... use `yourMatch.Groups[1]` to get the value out... your looking at the first result only and there is two results.

Comment: .net doesn't have that I don't bleieve